# Why doesn't a particle's velocity effect the strength exerted on it by an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Here is what I know:

$F = E  q = m  a$

so $a = \frac{E q}{ m}$

and we can increase the acceleration ($a$) of a particle in an electric field ($E$) by either decreasing its mass ($m$) or increasing its charge ($q$).

Here is where I am confused:

$a = \frac{v}{ t}$, thus $E = \frac{m v }{q t}$

Yet, increasing the velocity ($v$) of a particle traveling through an electric field has no effect on the electric field. Why not?

Comment: $a=v/t$ is wrong, it's $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that in this scenario the electric field is some given value - probably a constant - established as a parameter of the problem. If you've been given $E$, you can solve for $a$ (and therefore $v$). Or, having been given $a$, you can compute the necessary $E$ to account for such an acceleration. However, they are not independent in the sense that they cannot both be free parameters of the problem.

In other words, when you change $a$ you are not increasing or decreasing the affect of $E$ on the particle, you are merely recalculating the mathematically necessary electric field for this new kinematical problem.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity is a result of the electric field, not it is cause. In other words, the electric field is what causes the velocity to increase. You can control the electric field by an external source which will affect the velocity of the particle, but you can't control it by controlling the velocity of the particle.

There is one scenario in which the velocity of the accelerated particle could affect the electric field. If the particle is massive or if there s a huge number of particles, the work done by the electric field on them (to accelerate them) will be taken from the energy of the electric field. In such a case the electric field becomes *weaker* as the velocity of the massive particle/the huge number of particles is increased. That effect can be ignored for a small particle.

Comment: Particle velocity can be increased prior to injection into the field.

Comment: @user1910903 The initial velocity does not influence the field, it is simply added to the velocity at any other point in time. Your formula for the acceleration is only a special case, as jinawee pointed out. Even for a constant field it should be $a = \frac{v(t)-v(0)}{t}$.